# I'm trying to make a simple tic tac toe game with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to make a simple tic tac toe game with html and javascript, where a button is clicked, and the value of that button becomes "x", but when I click it, nothing happens.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<script>
function tic(a) {
document.getElementById(a).value = "x";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
Tic-Tac-Toe
</center>
<center>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input value=" " name="aa" type="button" onClick="tic("aa")">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " name="ab" type="button" onClick="tic("ab")">
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any IDs defined, which your code relies upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tic(a) {
    a.value = "x";
};
```

then :

```
<input value=" " name="aa" id="aa" type="button" onclick="tic(this);">
```

Comment: Your answer would be a lot more useful if you explained it.

Comment: It is useful  :Good brevity makes sense . Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, I meant "helpful".

Answer (score 3):

Do you notice something strange here?

```
onClick="tic("aa")"
```

have a look at the quotation marks. Your attribute value is actually

```
onClick="tic("
```

which is not valid JavaScript. Use different quotation marks inside the value:

```
onClick="tic('aa')"
```

---

The other problem is that there is no element with ID aa or ab, so `document.getElementById(a)` will return `null`. If you intend to refer to the buttons, you can either give them the IDs, or simply pass the element itself directly to the function:

```
<script>
function tic(element) {
   element.value = "x";
}
</script>

<input value=" " name="aa" type="button" onClick="tic(this)">
```

I recommend to read [these articles](http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) to learn more about event handling, and [about DOM](http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html).

Comment: I was in the middle of updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick="tic("aa")"` should be:

```
onClick="tic('aa')"
             ^--^-----------single quotes so you don't need to escape them
```

Also, you should use ids instead of names since you are using `getElementById`:

```
        <td> 
            <input value=" " id="aa" type="button" onClick="tic('aa')">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="ab" type="button" onClick="tic('ab')">
        </td>
```

Another option is to pass `this` as argument and then modify its value in the function instead.

Like:

```
function tic(el) {
   el.value = "x";
}
```

Pass it `this`:

```
tic(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work now. Your function is calling `document.getElementById()` but you only have `name=` set & not `id=`. So I have set `id=` values for the `<input>` buttons. Also adjusted the `onClick` values to be have single quotes for the values and a `;` after the function call.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<script>
function tic(a) {
document.getElementById(a).value = "x";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
Tic-Tac-Toe
</center>
<center>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input value=" " name="aa" id="aa" type="button" onClick="tic('aa');">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " name="ab" id="ab" type="button" onClick="tic('ab');">
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```